# How to determine if a Sign in with Apple credential is already associated with an app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app using Firebase Authentication with Sign in with Apple as an option. When users download my app on a new device and want to log in again, I need to know if their Apple ID (or private Apple ID) is already associated with an account.

My app uses anonymous accounts by default with the option to link to a different provider later. But with Sign in with Apple, if I attempt to link the credential, the credential is burnt.

Is there any way I can tell if the credential I receive from Sign in with Apple is a new one or an old one?

I tried to extract the email from the JWT so I could see if an account already exists, but Firebase [are removing the ability to query accounts by email on the client side](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection).

I feel like I must be missing something obvious so help is appreciated!

Comment: You won’t get the name, the name is only provided once. You should also be keeping the ID Apple gives you.

Comment: Check for existing account when viewDidAppear using ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate and show login or let user in as suggested in documentation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple